# Convert Class component to functional using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

I am trying to convert this to functional component using hooks but not having luck. How would I do this? (new to hooks). I have tried to follow documentation but I must not be understanding it. This should work the same way but with functional component using hooks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

```
    const texts = [
  ['Text 1', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
  ['Text 2', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
  ['Text 3', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
  ['Text 4', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
];


export default class Testing extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clickedText: [],
    };
  }

  handleClick = (i) => {
    this.setState({ clickedText: texts[i] });
  };

  render() {
    const { clickedText } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {texts.map((text, i) => (
          <button key={i} onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}>
            Click me {i + 1}
          </button>
        ))}
        {clickedText.length > 0 && <p>I clicked on button with text:</p>}
        <ul>
          {clickedText.map((t, i) => (
            <li key={`text-${i}`}>{t}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const texts = [
    ['Text 1', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
    ['Text 2', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
    ['Text 3', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
    ['Text 4', 'blah', 'sdklfj'],
];

const Testing = (props) => {
    // useState is the function component equivalent of the inherited 'setState'
    const [clickedText, setClickedText] = useState([]);

    const handleClick = (i) => {
        setClickedText(texts[i]);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {texts.map((text, i) => (
                <button key={i} onClick={() => handleClick(i)}>
                    Click me {i + 1}
                </button>
            ))}
            {clickedText.length > 0 && <p>I clicked on button with text:</p>}
            <ul>
                {clickedText.map((t, i) => (
                    <li key={`text-${i}`}>{t}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Testing;
```

Comment: It is not working on click `Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, forgot a `const`

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, sometimes I have to be shown and repeat it myself  a few times. I see where I messed up in my own.

Comment: `onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}` is wrong. remove `this`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to replace the current state in class components with the `useState` feature of the functional components. Please also read the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) of react about using the state in functional components. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-platform-9xn3q?file=/src/App.js:0-733)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const texts = [
  ["Text 1", "blah", "sdklfj"],
  ["Text 2", "blah", "sdklfj"],
  ["Text 3", "blah", "sdklfj"],
  ["Text 4", "blah", "sdklfj"]
];

const Testing = (props) => {
  const [clickedText, setClickedText] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (i) => {
    setClickedText(texts[i]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {texts.map((text, i) => (
        <button key={i} onClick={() => handleClick(i)}>
          Click me {i + 1}
        </button>
      ))}
      {clickedText.length > 0 && <p>I clicked on button with text:</p>}
      <ul>
        {clickedText.map((t, i) => (
          <li key={`text-${i}`}>{t}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Testing;
```

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, sometimes I have to be shown and repeat it myself  a few times. I see where I messed up in my own.

Comment: this seems much easier than class based components but I like to learn both.

Comment: yep it's much less complicated than class-based ones

Answer (score -1):

learn how to use useState, useRef, useEffect. in your example you dont need useEffect but you will need it.

here is your code with hooks:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
   const [clickedText, setClickedText] = useState([]);
   const texts = useRef([
     ["Text 1", "blah", "sdklfj"],
     ["Text 2", "blah", "sdklfj"],
     ["Text 3", "blah", "sdklfj"],
     ["Text 4", "blah", "sdklfj"]
]);

const handleClick = (i) => {
   setClickedText(texts.current[i]);
 };

 return (
    <div>
      {texts.current.map((text, i) => (
         <button key={i} onClick={() => handleClick(i)}>
             Click me {i + 1}
         </button>
      ))}
      {clickedText.length > 0 && <p>I clicked on button with text:</p>}
      <ul>
          {clickedText.map((t, i) => (
             <li key={`text-${i}`}>{t}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
      </div>
 );
 }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-waterfall-s0t0m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you this makes sense, sometimes I have to be shown and repeat it myself  a few times. I see where I messed up in my own.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28435902)

Comment: @Chris added inline code. thanks for the warning.